# How to fix 500 response in a Laravel project

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, github, composer-php

I cloned project 
https://github.com/SagarMaheshwary/laravel-react-beginners.git
and ran
`composer install`
`php artisan serve`
But localhost:8000 shows 500 Server Error and I can not see any error logs in the artisan console. How can I fix this problem?

I am using MacOS.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Normally you have to have configure your `.env` file and generate a key with `php artisan key:generate`.

Comment: Thank you. It is running well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Clone the github repo:

```sh
git clone https://github.com/SagarMaheshwary/laravel-react-beginners.git
```

2. Go the project directory:

```sh
cd laravel-react-beginners
```

3. Install the project dependencies:

```sh
composer install
```

4. Copy the `.env.example` to `.env` or simly rename it:

If linux:

```sh
cp .env.example .env
```

If windows:

```sh
copy .env.example .env
```

4. Create the application key:

```sh
php artisan key:generate
```

5. Start the laravel server:

```sh
php artisan serve
```